# How many recipes are there?

Tags: fiz

I recently completed the progression challenge to learn 60 recipes. I was under the impression that I had found every recipe (no more brewing Mousetrap Maibock!), until I found another recipe scrap...

How many recipes are there in total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer answered my question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340665/what-is-the-last-recipe-i-need-to-complete-the-recipe-archivist-achievement), adding:

> Trivia: There are actually more than 70 recipes in the game, but various ones like Tutorial Lite don't count toward the Recipe Archivist achievement family.

The official Fiz website, [www.brewfiz.com](http://www.brewfiz.com/), also advertises "70+ Recipes to discover."

However, not all recipes are unlocked from mice. You can unlock a few through story events; you unlock the Record Breaker from a random, non-story event, and you unlock some from reading recipe descriptions for a hint at a new recipe. For example, the recipe description for Dust Devil says "Vienna Malt might upgrade this little twister..." If you add some Vienna malt, you can unlock a new recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Ten batches of Mousetrap Maibock later, I am confident in stating there are 61 recipes, 60 of which may be normally brewed.