# What is the last recipe I need to complete the Recipe Archivist achievement?

Tags: fiz

I have 59/60, and have beaten the game three times already. I have completed every achievement/challenge except for Recipe Archivist. I also completed every event in my second playthrough of the game. I am missing one recipe. (One of them, the cloudhazer, I had to copy from the Wiki). I don't suppose it's the Tutorial Lite...? (I tried, but it didn't work).

Here are the 59 I have:

1. Assimilator
2. Bad Leroy
3. Bad Pathing Porter
4. Beryllium Erbium Blonde
5. Bitter Lester
6. BlonderBrew
7. Bonehead Surprise
8. Brewed Mother
9. Chimera
10. Cloudchaser
11. Cloudhazer
12. Dark Rider
13. Die Höhlenschatz
14. Dieter’s Mai Bock
15. Dust Devil
16. Eddy’s Terrib-ale
17. Esk’s Elite Bit-ter
18. Fiz
19. Get Off My Lawn Lager
20. Good Life Guy’s Not So Imperial Ale
21. Grubb’s Lite
22. Grubb’s Premium
23. Grüberheimer
24. Heartstopper
25. Hellspout
26. Hot as Helles
27. Icy Road
28. Ino’s Pale Ale
29. Intoxicated Ape IPA
30. Jet Lag
31. Kraken Stout
32. Limesucker IPA
33. Love at First Sip
34. Maneater
35. Marianas Quench
36. Matushka Stout
37. Midnight Train
38. Moustrap Maibock
39. Northbound Brown
40. Penny Pipe Ale
41. Plain Jane Pale Ale
42. Record Breaker
43. Red Kastle IRA
44. Red Keep IRA
45. Regal Seat
46. Rock Hawk Wheat
47. Rocky’s Blond Ambition
48. Shovel and Axe
49. Siegel’s Hoptometrist
50. Sigi’s Weiss
51. Smokebamberg
52. Southern Drawl IPA
53. Stella’s Call
54. Three Goddesses
55. Truck Punch Pale Ale
56. Whole Wheat Toast
57. Will Save IPA
58. Wrecking Ball
59. XPereienced Brew

Comment: I completed this game a looong time ago, and [apparently found all 60 (61?)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/149467/31508). Unfortunately it's been too long for me to remember (and I no longer have the save game). Have you tried simply brewing Mousetrap Maibock over and over?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have everything from the mice already. :(

Comment: I did a bit of digging and found [Igor's Mystery Recipe](https://bitbybitstudios.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/174153-i-can-t-figure-out-igor-s-mystery-recipe-for-the-malty-magnate-event) but I'm not sure if that's applicable or not

Comment: That's the matushka stout, unlocked in a story event.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the developer of the game -- thanks for playing!

There are 64 possible recipes counted toward Recipe Archivist, you need 60 of them.  The tricky ones that people usually miss are derivatives of existing recipes.  These are found by substituting ingredients much in the way you changed the **Recipe Grid** from *Grubb's Lite* to make *Grubb's Premium*.

There are 2 in particular (both included in your list) that spawn a series of recipes if you pay attention to the **Recipe Description** shown in the **Brew Menu**, and then make the suggested substitutions.

One of them is:

> Stella's Call

Which leads to:

> Kahn's Scream > Adrian's Cry > Rosebud's Whisper

and another is:

> Dust Devil

Which leads to:

> Cyclone > Fujita Five

Trivia: There are actually more than 70 recipes in the game, but various ones like *Tutorial Lite* don't count toward the Recipe Archivist achievement family.